# Consula de dos tablas relacionadas con Eloquent - Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, join

Buenas antes que nada gracias por leer mi pregunta, he realizado una consulta a mi base de datos relacionando 2 tablas he realizado esto haciendo uso de JOIN y me preguntaba como se podria hacer la misma consulta con Eloquent.
La tabla principal es cat_tabulator_histories y esta tabla esta relacionada con cat_contract_types y cat_sub_contract_type, quiero obtener los registros de cat_tabulator_histories trayendo consigo los registros que estan relacionados.

Les comparto mi query en JOIN para que se entienda mejor:

```
 $tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')
            ->where('cat_tabulator_id', $id)
            ->join('cat_contract_types', 'cat_contract_types.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.cat_contract_type_id')
            ->join('cat_sub_contract_types', 'cat_sub_contract_types.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.sub_contract_type_id')
            ->select('cat_tabulator_histories.id as id', 'cat_tabulator_histories.name as name', 'cat_tabulator_histories.base_salary_cents as salary_cents', 'cat_tabulator_histories.compensation_cents as compensation_cents', 'cat_tabulator_histories.is_active as active', 'cat_tabulator_histories.created_at as created_at','cat_tabulator_histories.start_date as start_date','cat_tabulator_histories.end_date as end_date', 'cat_tabulator_histories.date_active as date_active', 'cat_contract_types.name as type_contract', 'cat_sub_contract_types.name as type_subcontract')
            ->orderBy('cat_tabulator_histories.start_date', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Gracias por sus repuestas cabe resaltar que mis tablas ya estan relacionadas a nivel de modelo de nuevo muchas gracias cualquier opinión de por donde puedo iniciar me seria de mucha ayuda.

He logrado hacer la consulta con eloquent de esta manera:

```
$tabulatorsHistory = CatTabulatorHistory::where('cat_tabulator_id', $tabulatorOriginal->id)
                ->with('contract','subContract')
                ->get();
```

Ahora el problema con el que me enfrento es que me trae toda la tabla relacionada de esta manera:

```
 {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "PRUEBA1.0",
            "base_salary_cents": 2000000,
            "daily_salary_cents": 0,
            "compensation_cents": 1000000,
            "start_date": "2021-12-15",
            "end_date": "2021-12-30",
            "is_active": false,
            "budget_code": null,
            "gross_allocation": 0,
            "concepts": null,
            "cat_contract_type_id": 1,
            "cat_tabulator_id": 72,
            "sub_contract_type_id": 1,
            "date_active": "2021-12-02 10:36:27",
            "created_at": "2021-12-02T16:35:25.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-02T16:35:25.000000Z",
            "contract": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "BASE/ESTRUCTURA/OPERATIVO CONF",
                "christmas_bonus_days": 90,
                "gratification_days": null,
                "holidays": 20,
                "isActive": true,
                "is_unionized": false,
                "cat_vacations_type_id": 1,
                "cat_sat_contract_type_id": null,
                "cat_sat_work_day_type_id": null,
                "cat_sat_employee_regime_id": null,
                "schedules_id": null,
                "created_at": "2021-10-29T21:35:08.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-29T21:35:08.000000Z"
            },
            "sub_contract": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "BASE",
                "cat_contract_type_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-10-29T21:35:12.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-29T21:35:12.000000Z"
            }
        },
```

Yo quiero solo el name de cada relación.

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado/investigado y el problema concreto con el que te encontraste.

Comment: Ya actualice, gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Bien! En la doc muestran cómo [cargar columnas específicas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns) de la relación. Como nota, siempre deberás cargar la llave primaria, y si la llave foránea está en la tabla del modelo relacionado, también tendrás que cargarla para que eager load funcione

Comment: Excelente @porloscerrosΨ te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulta con JOIN:

```
 $tabulatorsHistory = DB::table('cat_tabulator_histories')
            ->where('cat_tabulator_id', $id)
            ->join('cat_contract_types', 'cat_contract_types.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.cat_contract_type_id')
            ->join('cat_sub_contract_types', 'cat_sub_contract_types.id', '=', 'cat_tabulator_histories.sub_contract_type_id')
            ->select('cat_tabulator_histories.id as id', 'cat_tabulator_histories.name as name', 'cat_tabulator_histories.base_salary_cents as salary_cents', 'cat_tabulator_histories.compensation_cents as compensation_cents', 'cat_tabulator_histories.is_active as active', 'cat_tabulator_histories.created_at as created_at','cat_tabulator_histories.start_date as start_date','cat_tabulator_histories.end_date as end_date', 'cat_tabulator_histories.date_active as date_active', 'cat_contract_types.name as type_contract', 'cat_sub_contract_types.name as type_subcontract')
            ->orderBy('cat_tabulator_histories.start_date', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Consulta con Eloquent:

```
$tabulatorsHistory = CatTabulatorHistory::where('cat_tabulator_id', $tabulatorOriginal->id)
                ->with('contract','subContract')
                ->get();
```

Si quieres obtener solo un campo de cada tabla en este caso yo utilice el campo name:

```
$tabulatorsHistory = CatTabulatorHistory::where('cat_tabulator_id', $tabulatorOriginal->id)
                ->with(['contract:id,name,cat_contract_types.id', 'subContract:id,name,cat_sub_contract_types.id'])
                ->get();
```

[cargar columnas especificas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)